# jQuery button takes value from input and do an action - how does it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've got a small piece of code here

```
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="pass" value="QWERTY">
            <button for="pass">Submit!</button>
```

and jquery action

```
$("button").click(function(){
        var value=$("input[id=pass]").attr("value");
        if (value==="QWERTY"){
            alert("Good!");
        };
```

and it doesnt work. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: What you exactly want to get worked? can you be specific?

Comment: For one thing, you have an obvious syntax error. You're missing a closing `)`.

Comment: You realise that `attr('value')` will return the value from the HTML, rather than the `value` property of the element from the DOM?  (The `value` *attribute* won't change, whereas the `value` *property* will (if the user types something into, or interacts with, the element/node)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var value=$("input#pass").val();
    if ( value === "QWERTY"){
        alert("Good!");
    }
});
```

jQuery has it's own built in function for fetching values from input fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent the default action from triggering when the button is clicked (otherwise the form will be submitted, and the JS will not execute). You should also use `val()` when accessing an input's value.

You should also wrap your code inside the DOMReady handler, to ensure that the DOM is accessible when your script is run.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
$(function() {  
    $("button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var the_value = $("#pass").val();

        if(value == "QWERTY")
        {
            alert("Good!");
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It's more **optimized...**

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value=$("#pass")[0].value;
    if (value==="QWERTY"){
        alert("Good!");
};
```

You can also remove the "for" attribute on the button, it's non correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you don't forget the `});` at last and have put the code into dom ready callback function. [The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/RezNR/)

And you could write it like below:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if ($('#pass').val()==="QWERTY"){
        alert("Good!");
    };
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `val()` always return a string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a syntax error. You need to make sure you close your function curly brace and your click close paren.

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    $("button").click(function () {
        var value = $("input[id=pass]").attr("value");
        if (value === "QWERTY") {
            alert("Good!");
        }
    });
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pandaPowder/5VjeD/3/